# How to write a covering letter when I have no idea what I'm applying on?

Tags: applications

I got a letter from a company saying that they found my profile on a careerdatabase(?) and are really interested in having a talk with me.

I found out that the company itself is active in various really different fields. For example they themself are conveying jobs in tehir own database and offering it as service while they are also known for selling insurances.

Since I'm looking for a position as software developer and the phonenumber they asked me to call is located where the office of their IT seems to be located, I'm assuming they are not trying to to convey me but hire me for themselves.

Anyways here is now my problem:

When I called them yesterday, I got told that the responsible person is not in house for the whole week and they asked me to send them an application within this week so that it speeds up the process as soon the responsible person is available again next week.

But I have no idea what to write into my covering letter.
Usually I write in why I think I'm the best fit for the position and what I made before that makes me proficient in what they do, but here I have no idea at all.

I can't get any idea what their IT might be responsible for since the company is active in so many different fields and I also have no idea which of my skills made them get interested in me.

So how should I design my apllication/convering letter in a situation like this?

Comment: Don't apply at all before you know it.

Comment: @deviantfan: So I should ignore so request of an application adn jsut call them again next week? I feel like this would put me in a light of unresponsability

Comment: Well, depends if you like to gamble. Gambling can reap great rewards, but it's definitively a risk. Your call, I'd say.

Comment: Communicate this to them. There's nothing wrong with being honest!

Comment: Is a covering letter even necessary in cases where the company contacts you in the first place?

Comment: This job is going to be sea-monkeys  - don't waste your time. At best you're going to be on site trying to generate consultant work (for which you'll get paid 10% of the rate).

Comment: Who told you to apply? Can you call the person back and ask what the position is that you should be applying for?

Comment: @Brandin: That person told me allready when she told me that the responsible person isn't there this week, that she can't help me because she doesn't know what this was about. So I don't need to call them again, at least if I expect to get the same person on the wire.

Comment: @TheMathemagician: How do you mean this? If they initiate the contact Is that allready a redflag in it self, or how do you get on this conclusion?

Comment: @Zaibis Then you should call next week when the hiring manage is there.

Comment: Yes it's a huge red flag. They sent an identical letter to everyone in the database who matched their query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd do two things because they contacted me cold without telling me a position.

Firstly I'd take it as a red flag that they're asking for paperwork with no prep. And I wouldn't give it.

Secondly on the offchance it might be real I'd leave my number with them and ask them to get the recruiter to give me a call when he's back.

The first means I don't waste much time and effort. The second gives me a stronger negotiating position if there is an actual job. If they're chasing you around you're in a much better position than if you're running in circles doing a performance for them.

Comment: So since I allready did the call (and in that call they allready asked me for leaving my number) You say I now just should wait for them calling me, and if they don't do, it probably not the best position anyways?

Comment: Yes that would be my judgement

Comment: For anyone who is curious: I did not act at all, and they indeed did contact me and made a decent offer which I'm probably going to accept.

Comment: Excellent result, good luck

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me like you have two options: either make a large(r) cover letter or wait for the person in question to return and call again.

Honestly, I would wait for the person in question to return and ask for what position(s) he was thinking about.

Why?

- Maybe you don't want the job they are offering
- You weren't the one that initiated, and you clearly require more Information
- For me it shows a red flag someone would start recruiting someone and then go away for a week

This could carry the risk that someone who didnt care about this is getting the unknown job.

If you are **in need of** the job, just wait it out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested in what you've seen so far?  You don't know much about this company or the job, but what makes you want to continue talking to them?

The cover letter should say what about the company and work looks interesting to you, what you like doing, what you bring to the table.  After all, if it turns out they want you for something you're not interested in, then the cover letter can help them realize it without taking up more of your time.